# scrollbar-width:thin not working n Firefox

Tags: html, css

I just implemented the new css scrollbar-color and scrollbar-width in Firefox 67.  The scrollbar-width does not work.  Whether I set it to auto, thin or none it shows the same width.  I want it to be thin, but it's not thin.

Here's how I implemented it.

```
:root{
  scrollbar-color:  rgb(75,75,75) black;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
```

}

It looks good, but it's not thin.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Hmm... This code works for me. Are you using MacOS?

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows 10

Comment: I cannot speak for Windows, but in MacOS the scrollbar properties are affected by system settings; I had to change my scrollbar preferences to "always show" in order to see the changed colors (thinness always worked). Perhaps there is a similar Windows setting for scrollbars?

Comment: Try this [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar)

Comment: Thanks for the tips about the OS, and perfect-scollbar.

Comment: Update us if you find a solution.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that if I find a solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: @RTC222 I know it's been two years, but did you find a solution?

Comment: Still not working in Firefox latest developer edition