# Scrollbar color not being set

Tags: css, firefox

Everywhere I look, the `scrollbar-color` property has [full support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_scrollbar-color) in Firefox.

When I try it, `scrollbar-width: thin` is applied, but not `scrollbar-color`:

```css
* {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: red transparent;
}

p {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab ipsam iste numquam saepe, praesentium iusto porro sed amet consequuntur nemo voluptatem, qui itaque dolore facilis dolor eius illo, doloribus culpa harum. Incidunt similique quos aspernatur odit,
  magnam dicta consequatur sit modi quo pariatur quidem illum voluptatum placeat non aliquam maxime expedita, nemo in repellat rem. Maiores ipsa veniam, illum dolores inventore in eligendi ea unde quas excepturi iure beatae molestiae accusantium magnam
  accusamus ut cumque eaque. Ex deserunt aspernatur eaque aut, voluptates aliquid molestiae eius ad a molestias, velit, totam est quidem. Dicta error eius dolorum, modi blanditiis necessitatibus ad!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab ipsam iste numquam saepe, praesentium iusto porro sed amet consequuntur nemo voluptatem, qui itaque dolore facilis dolor eius illo, doloribus culpa harum. Incidunt similique quos aspernatur odit,
  magnam dicta consequatur sit modi quo pariatur quidem illum voluptatum placeat non aliquam maxime expedita, nemo in repellat rem. Maiores ipsa veniam, illum dolores inventore in eligendi ea unde quas excepturi iure beatae molestiae accusantium magnam
  accusamus ut cumque eaque. Ex deserunt aspernatur eaque aut, voluptates aliquid molestiae eius ad a molestias, velit, totam est quidem. Dicta error eius dolorum, modi blanditiis necessitatibus ad!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab ipsam iste numquam saepe, praesentium iusto porro sed amet consequuntur nemo voluptatem, qui itaque dolore facilis dolor eius illo, doloribus culpa harum. Incidunt similique quos aspernatur odit,
  magnam dicta consequatur sit modi quo pariatur quidem illum voluptatum placeat non aliquam maxime expedita, nemo in repellat rem. Maiores ipsa veniam, illum dolores inventore in eligendi ea unde quas excepturi iure beatae molestiae accusantium magnam
  accusamus ut cumque eaque. Ex deserunt aspernatur eaque aut, voluptates aliquid molestiae eius ad a molestias, velit, totam est quidem. Dicta error eius dolorum, modi blanditiis necessitatibus ad!</p>
```

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877231/scrollbar-widththin-not-working-n-firefox#comment100303705_56877231) suggests you need to change it in the Firefox settings but I can't find anywhere to do this.

Am I missing something or has it suddenly become deprecated?

**UPDATE**

Looking in `about:config`, both properties are set to true:

[image: Screenshot of both properties enabled]

Comment: it's working fine on my Firefox

Comment: That's really strange. Have you changed any browser settings for it?

Comment: no, you probably did?

Comment: Looking in `about:config` both properties are set to true

Comment: Can you used any theme in Firefox ?

Comment: How do you mean @RayeesAC?

Comment: I mean like this [custom scrollbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-scrollbars/)

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? On my machine, FF 68 (ESR) does have the about:config entries, but your snippet doesn't work. FF 81 (Nightly) on the other hand, does not have the about:config entries, but the snippet does work.

Comment: It's just the standard 79.0 (64-bit) @MrLister

Comment: Checking your code snippet and working (scrollbar thumb is red) - Firefox 79.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks @AsafS. it's more than likely whoever uses the site will see it correctly if they're using FF. Must just be my browser.